# hidden variables for buttons causing problems

Tags: php, variables, hidden

Here is my code in php. I have a php creditcard confirmation page, with 2 button, edit details and submit. I have an init file which will perform tasks based on what cc_confirm is and what editval is, confirm and editing details respectively.

`if($_POST['cc_confirm1']=='y' && $_POST['$editval']!='y' && !isset($editval)) 
{echo '<input name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Edit Details" /><input name="editval" type="hidden" value="y" /><input name="cc_confirm" type="hidden" value="n" />';

}
if($_POST['cc_confirm1']=='y' && $_POST['$editval']!='y' && !isset($editval)){
    echo '<input name="submitbtn1" type="submit" value="Submit Card" /><input name="card1" type="hidden" value="y" /><input name="cc_confirm" type="hidden" value="y" />';`

Now the problem is, because I am using two hidden items, always the one at the bottom is being executed. For this code, if i press on edit details, the details are being submitted, the credit card is being runned and then edit page is shown after that, which does not serve the purpose.

If i interchange both button codes, then even for submit card, it is showing only edit page details without submitting card. I have tried to change the name  of the buttons but no use.How can i avoid this problem? Appreciate any effort to solve.

Comment: @Scorpion King: Why are you using hidden buttons?!!

Comment: I am using them because my cms is built in such a way. I am not able to use any other method. If i did, it would break the whole code of credit card systems so i am not messing with it.

Comment: did you try to set them as disabled? instead of hidden?

Comment: No, these are not the values on that page, these are the values for the init.php file which will the functions according to what values are specified. For example, if editval is y, then the editpage will be shown and same case for cc_confirm, the api will execute if it is y.

Comment: so..you cannot only have one hidden field output at a time? Or have the one not intended for use be output with a different value than "y"?

Comment: Consider the situation where, you enter billing info and credit card info, on the next page i am showing, 'please confirm these details are correct' page. Here i am copying those details and showing them to the user and providing the user with 2 buttons, edit detials and submit card info. So these two buttons are mandatory and the hidden values for each button will direct them to the appropriate function.

I have tried to change the value of "y" and set it "n" for the other button, but whatever value is there for the second button, only that is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split up the conditions by assigning a value to them

```
$continue = 0;
if($_POST['cc_confirm1']=='y'){
$continue++;
}
if($_POST['$editval']!='y'){
$continue++;
}
else{
$continue = 0;
$reason = 'editval';
}
if(!isset($editval)) {
$continue++;
}
else{
$continue = 0;
$reason = 'noeditval';
}
if($continue > 0){
echo '<input name="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Edit Details" /><input name="editval" type="hidden" value="y" /><input name="cc_confirm" type="hidden" value="n" />';
} 
else{
    if($reason == 'editval'){
    //Process
    }
    elseif($reason == 'noeditval'){
    //Process
    }
}
```

Comment: THanks for your reply. Your code, looks nice, but the problem is that, the conditions for both the buttons are the same. So $continue value will increase for sure. If there were any condition which is not same for both buttons then I would have not had any problem. Both these buttons need to be shown but the hidden values need to be specific to the button that is pressed... :(